# How to determine type from type aliasing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

After I declare an alias `t1 = typing.List[int]` or `t2=typing.List[double]`, how do I determine from`t1` that it is a `List[int]` and from `t2` that it is a `List[double]`? Are there some hidden attributes or functions of `t1` and `t2` that can help?

Comment: Do you mean statically or at runtime? At runtime, you do it the same way you would have done it if you had used `typing.List[int]` directly. Granted, I'm not currently sure what that way would be.

Comment: I mean at run time.  If I see some variable t, what can I do to figure out that t is a `typing.List[int`]  or a `typing.List[double]`  or a `typing.List[something]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interactively, your most useful option is probably

```
>>> t1
typing.List[int]
```

If you want to inspect it in a program, you can look at things like `__name__`, `__parameters__`, or whether `issubclass` reports it as a subclass of `typing.List`:

```
>>> t1.__name__
'List'
>>> t1.__parameters__
(<class 'int'>,)
>>> issubclass(t1, typing.List)
True
```

Comment: Ah ok, that's more of what I am looking for,  the `.__parameters__`  property.  Also in what case would `__parameters__` give a tuple of 2 or more things ?  
Thanks

Comment: @VuNguyen: For a generic with more than one type parameter, such as `typing.Mapping[str, str]`.